# What is the cheapest and long distance (20-30 m) way for communicating Raspberry Pi and attiny (or any other microcontroller)?

Tags: networking, arduino, home-automation, communication

I need to make Raspberry Pi as my master and communicate with several slave devices (5-6 Attiny2313 in my case) that are kept 20-30 m (65-100 ft) away. Following are the requirements:

1. cheap (preferably no external hardware)
2. uses minimum number of wires (preferably two wires)
3. speed can be very low.. it is not an issue... 
   i just need to turn some devices on and off at the slave end.
4. reliable over distances of 20-30 m (65-100 ft)

Please suggest me some communication protocol that can handle all these requirements.

Comment: serial communication should work. also, check http://whathaveyoutried.com please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using RS-485.  You can attach several devices to one pair of wires with very reasonably-priced hardware, and the interface chips usually include good isolation to prevent ESD problems.

Use the slowest baud rate that is acceptable to the amount of data you need to communicate.

Comment: Some details would help: what RS-485 chips work? What kind of wiring? What libraries are there for Raspberry Pi and ATTiny for managing RS-485?

Comment: Yes, this is *technically* an answer, but unless you provide some background details and info on how to program/use it, it requires the OP to do more research, instead of being able to continue on with their project. We are glad you are getting involved, however, this answer could use some work.

Comment: can someone please guide us to some references for using rs485 and Pi

Answer (score 2):

Should be doable with a [RF Link Transmitter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10534) on the Raspberry Pi and [RF Link Receiver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10532)s on the remote boards. You'll have to use a Manchester encoding library on the Raspberry Pi (like [this](https://github.com/maditnerd/radioattiny) one [untested]), and a decoding library (like [this](http://mchr3k.github.io/arduino-libs-manchester/)) on your microcontrollers. Use short messages (say 1 byte address, 1 byte command) and put wire antennae on the transmitters and receivers.

Note that this will send **only**; you'll have no idea if the microcontrollers have done their job properly.